# What's the proper word for someone who keeps track of time and other events during a game?

Tags: single-word-requests

I occasionally volunteer for our community's inline hockey club to keep time or record the events of a game, for example penalties and goals. We typically sit in a wooden hut next to the rink and enter the data in a computer, and manage a chronometer linked to the main public display.

I guess the part about keeping time could be called a *timekeeper*, but is there a proper term for both functions? In French we call this "officiel de table", but I have no idea what to call this in English.

Comment: Do you mean *scorekeeper*?

Comment: *scorekeeper* would be the term for the other person serving in the hut, yes. But I'm looking for a term that covers both scorekeeper and timekeeper.

Comment: Adding ice hockey to your title, would better convey your specific meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brief Google search suggests that the term **off-ice official** may be used as a hypernym for both *scorekeeper* and *timekeeper*.

> Minor hockey is very fortunate to have a great base of volunteers who
>   assist at hockey games as scorekeepers (writes up the game sheet) and
>   timekeepers (works the clock).
>
> When you are one of the people working in the timkeeper's box and
>   penalty box area, you are considered an off-ice official.  Thus, your
>   role for the game is to be an impartial game official.  Please do not
>   debate or argue calls with referees when you are working as an off-ice
>   official.

http://saskatoon.goalline.ca/news.php?news_id=473567

> All teams should be reminded of the role of Timekeepers and
>   Scorekeepers (Off-Ice Officials) in Minor Hockey games. There have
>   been some concerns in the past and I hope this will clarify the
>   responsibilities volunteer parents are expected to adhere to, when
>   acting as a Timekeeper and/or Scorekeeper.

http://www.hockeynovascotia.ca/user/File/Timekeepers%20and%20Scorekeepers.pdf

Comment: Once you know what to google for, the answer comes of itself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_(ice_hockey)#Off-ice_officials